# Feign client sorting problem with Turkish characters into response

Tags: sorting, feign, openfeign

I use feign to make request to another microservice with pageable and my custom encoder to manage sorting/paging;

```
@GetMapping(
    value = {"/add-ben"},
    produces = {"application/json"}
)
BaseResponse<MyPageImpl<AddBenDTO>> getAddBenDTOList(@SpringQueryMap RequestGetAddBen request, Pageable pageable);
```

I am using below JSON to use pageable;

```
{
     "offset": 0,
     "sort": "name,DESC",
     "unpaged": true,
     "paged": true,
     "pageNumber": 0,
     "pageSize": 0
}
```

After the response accepted, I saw that the '*name*' values are sorted into *DESCENDING* order with using "*Turkish*" characters at first *(not starting from Z, but with turkish characters such as İ,Ü,Ş is at the beginning)*;

```
{
  "data": {
"content": [
  {
    (...)
    "name": "İSDEMİR ADDBEN TANIMI",
  },
  {
    (...)
    "name": "ÜCRETSİZ HAYAT SİGORTA"
  },
  {
    (...)
    "name": "ZUNICO _ADD BEN"
  },
  {
    (...)
    "name": "TPATVAKF_ FON",
  },
  {
   (...)
    "name": "PROMET END.VE TİC.LAST."
  },
  {
    (...)
    "name": "OYAK RENAULT OTOMOBİL FABRİKALARI A.Ş."
  }
], (...)
}
```

I think, this is related with the default charset. According to [feign doc.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-openfeign/docs/current/reference/html/#springencoder-configuration) **UTF-8** is the default charset.

How can I correct the sorting with correct order including Turkish characters also?

Thanks